# Controlling android Keyboard focus with code (particularly preference fragment)

Tags: android, android-keypad

I'm writing a app that deals with input and output over USB with an IOIO-OTG board - I want to be able to navigate my app using button inputs from the IOIO, should be fine in my main activity if I understand with something like

```
myBtn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
myBtn.requestFocus();
```

Two areas that I am not sure about controlling:

- My settings page  (PreferenceFragment)
- The soft keyboard for text entry

Any good ideas how I might solve this or workaround it somehow would be most helpful!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Ideally, can I control the android soft keyboard and settings preference focus with code. Or can I send keypress events to android in code (From the reading I've seen this is tricky)